# How do I await this callback method to perform logic on the return data?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, silverlight, async-await

So I'm working in Silverlight right now unfortunately for the first time. I'm decently familiar with callbacks, but I'm not entirely sure how to convert this method to be synchronous to perform logic on the order data.

I've been frequently told that making this synchronous was ill-advised, but my goal is to check if certain fields have been modified in the XAML UI and are different from what exists in the database. Then prompt for a reason for the change. If there is a better way to go about this, I'd love to know.

I'm in Silverlight 5 with .Net Framework 4.0 in VS 2013

Thank you! Here's the async order provider:

```cs
public void GetOrder(string ordNumber, Action<Func<OrderLoadResults>> callback)
{
    String exStr = String.Format("{0}.{1}() --> received an empty value for",
                              this.GetType().Name,
                              MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name);
    if (ordNumber == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("ordNumber", exStr);
    }

    if (callback == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("callback", exStr);
    }

    IOrderServiceAsync channel = CreateChannel();
    AsyncCallback asyncCallback = ar => GetOrderCallback(callback, ar);
    channel.BeginGetOrderByOrdNumber(ordNumber, asyncCallback.ThreadSafe(), channel);
}
```

And here's what I'm doing with it:

```cs
public List<ATMModifiedFieldModel> CheckForATMModifiedFields()
{
    if (!_order.Stops.Items.Any(x => x.ModelState == ModelState.Modified))
    {
        return null;
    }
    List<StopModel> oldStop = new List<StopModel>();

    Provider.OrderProvider orderProvider = new Provider.OrderProvider();
              
    //Looking to convert this method to sync to pull the order info out to compare against          
    //orderProvider.GetOrder(_order.Item.OrdHdrNumber.ToString(),getResult => OnGetOrderComplete(getResult));           

    List<ATMModifiedFieldModel> modifiedFields = new List<ATMModifiedFieldModel>();


    foreach (StopModel stop in _order.Stops.Items)
    {
        if (stop.ModelState == ModelState.Modified)
        {
            foreach (string ATMFieldName in Enum.GetNames(typeof(ATMFields)))
            {
                string beforeValue = "before value"; //Should check the value in the database
                string afterValue = stop.GetType().GetProperty(ATMFieldName).GetValue(stop, null).ToString();
                if (beforeValue != afterValue)
                {
                    modifiedFields.Add(new ATMModifiedFieldModel(ATMFieldName, beforeValue, afterValue, stop.StpNumber, "Stop"));
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return modifiedFields;
}
```

Comment: I wonder if using [TaskFactory.FromAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskfactory.fromasync) is an option? _"Creates a Task that represents a pair of begin and end methods that conform to the Asynchronous Programming Model pattern."_

Comment: So it would create a task from a begin and end method (The call and callback) and then I could just await that task?

Comment: Looks that way. Might be worth a try, at least.